# changing view from controller is not triggering view update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

I have an application where on homepage I am showing all the buddies(from a json using GET) on the page. I have a button to add a buddy on homepage.
On clicking, it takes me to a different view with forms fields to enter the buddy details. 
After submitting details I am again taken to the homepage which should render the newly added buddy with other buddies.

Everything is working alright. But the only problem is on returning back to the homepage after submitting buddy details, the page is not reflecting the newly added buddy to the view. However the scope is getting updated.

I have tried using $scope.$apply() and $scope.$digest() as mentioned here [angular.js: model update doesn't trigger view update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185753/angular-js-model-update-doesnt-trigger-view-update) but it is not updating my view. Also I am using the same controller for my homepage and adding the buddy so that my scope is same.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Is there is any other way I can implement the same?

My code goes here.

Home.html view

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to My Buddy List</h1>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#/add_buddy">Add Buddy</a>
</div>
<h2>My Buddies</h2>
<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media col-md-6" ng-repeat="buddy in buddies|filter:search">
    <a class="pull-left thumbnail" href="#/buddy/{{buddy.id}}">
        <img class="media-object" width="100" ng-rc="img/{{buddy.image_name}}.jpg" alt="{{buddy.username}}">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">{{buddy.username | uppercase}}
            <span class="badge">{{buddy.status}}</span>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <strong>First Name:</strong> {{buddy.first_name | capitalize}}<br/>
            <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{buddy.last_name | capitalize}}<br/>
            <strong>Status:</strong> {{buddy.status | capitalize}}<br/>
            <strong>Type:</strong> {{buddy.type | capitalize}} Buddy
            <a class="trashcan" data-ng-click="removeBuddy(buddy.id)" ><img class="trashcan" src="img/trashcan.png" alt="Delete"</a>
        </p>

    </div>
</li>
```

Add Buddy view (add_buddy.html)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <small><a href="#">Go Back</a></small>
    <h3>Add Buddy</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">        
    <form name="buddyForm" class="app-form">
        <label>User name</label> : <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.userName" required><br/>
        <label>First name</label> : <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" required><br/>
        <label>Last name</label> : <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" ><br/>
        <label>Email</label> : <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" ><br/>
        <!--label>Comments</label> : <textarea type="textarea" name="bio" ng-model="user.bio" ></textarea><br/-->
        <button class="submitButton" data-ng-click="addThisBuddy(user)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.addThisBuddy = function() {
    $scope.newBuddy = [{
        id: 100,
        first_name: $scope.user.firstName,
        last_name: "Anand",
        birthday: "05/23/1998",
        starred: "true",
        username: $scope.user.userName,
        image_name: "anand",
        type: "Hometown",
        bio: "Viswanathan Anand was born on 11 December.",
        last_login: "05/23/2016",
        email: "tmoore@devshare.biz"
    }];

    $scope.buddies = $scope.buddies.concat($scope.newBuddy);
    $location.path('home'); //skipping to view the newly added buddy on homepage
    $scope.$apply(); //tried but not updating view
    $scope.$digest();  //tried but not updating view
};
```

My app.js containing routing

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeController'});
 $routeProvider.when('/buddy/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/buddy.html', controller: 'BuddyController'});
 $routeProvider.when('/type/:type', {templateUrl: 'partials/buddy_type.html', controller: 'BuddyTypeController'});
 $routeProvider.when('/starred', {templateUrl: 'partials/starred_buddy.html', controller: 'StarredController'});
 $routeProvider.when('/add_buddy', {templateUrl: 'partials/add_buddy.html', controller: 'HomeController'});
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});
```

EDIT Notes:

After doing more search, I found that changing the view using $location is reloading the controller. Therefore, the scope gets updated and is reverted back to its former state. 
Is there any way to bypass that?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$scope.addThisBuddy` function in the `BuddyController`? Then, when you reference `$scope`, it is referencing the scope of the Add Buddy view, not the Home view.

Comment: I am using the same controller for both the views. My $scope.addThisBuddy function is in the HomeController. If I do console.log, I am able to view the updated Buddylist but the view is not getting updated.

Comment: I think it is the $location.path; it resets all controllers. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485117/angularjs-location-path-change-without-all-controllers-resetting) Can you try to do console.log _after_ the $location.path code?

Comment: I did the console.log after $location.path. It's updating the scope with the new buddy. Though the view not updated.